# Erase–remove idiom c++ (without friend function)

Tags: c++

I have two classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

enum class Programm{Koch, Normal, Bunt, Fein};

class KleidSt {
private:
    string bezeichnung;
    int gewicht;
    Programm Pflegehinweis;

public:
    KleidSt(string bezeichnung, int gewicht);
    KleidSt(string bezeichnung, int gewicht, Programm Pflegehinweis);
    int get_gewicht() const;
    bool vertraeglich(Programm)const;
    int get_Pflegehinweis() const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const KleidSt& kleid);
};


class WaschM{
private:
    int ladungsgewicht;
    vector<KleidSt> wasch;
public:
    WaschM(int ladungsgewicht);
    void zuladen(const vector<KleidSt>& z);
    void waschen(Programm);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const WaschM& kleid);
    int programme() const;
    vector<KleidSt> aussortieren(Programm pr);
};
```

I want to create the function `vector<KleidSt> aussortieren(Programm)`, that will delete all elements from `wasch` vector, if these elements will have `Pflegehinweis` attribute higher(by using `static_cast<int>(elem)` function) then is defined by `aussortieren` function and will return a vector of deleted elements.

My first try was to use Erase–remove idiom:

```
vector<KleidSt> WaschM::aussortieren(Programm pr){
    wasch.erase(remove_if(begin(wasch), end(wasch), vertraeglich(pr)), end(wasch));
    return wasch;
}
```

And here `vertraeglich(pr)` does the job, that I described above.
But it's clearly returns error, because  `vertraeglich` function was defined out of the scope of class `WaschM`. The question is: how can I use Erase–remove idiom(or maybe some other variants), such that code will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for a lambda function

```
vector<KleidSt> WaschM::aussortieren(Programm pr){
    wasch.erase(
        remove_if(
            begin(wasch),
            end(wasch), 
            [&](const KleidSt& k){ return k.vertraeglich(pr); }), 
        end(wasch));
    return wasch;
}
```

Untested code.

Comment: @john look again. There is no mention of the `^` character anywhere on that page. A lambda capture can use `=` or `&`, but not `^`. In this case, use `&` so `pr` is captured by reference and not by value

Comment: I believe you mean `&` (or `=`). `^` is bitwise xor.

Comment: Gosh, I was completely blind, it's fixed now, thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function.

```
vector<KleidSt> WaschM::aussortieren(Programm pr){
    wasch.erase(remove_if(begin(wasch),
                          end(wasch),
                          [pr](KleidSt const& item) {return item.vertraeglich(pr);},
                          end(wasch));
    return wasch;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `=` and not `&` in the capture list? Is `=pr` even legal?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that was an oversight.